# Code editor with lesscss support?

Tags: css, windows-7, editor, less

Do you know a good code editor that supports the [less](http://lesscss.org/) syntax?

I tried Netbeans with the lesscss module and it sucks, no auto-complete, highlighting not accurate (and Netbeans doesn't even know CSS 3)...

It also needs to have good PHP, HTML and JS support:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextMate on MacOS, SublimeText on Linux/Windows.

Comment: doesn't look like it has syntax highlighting, but looks really cool :D Do you know how could I make autocomplete fire automatically, without having to press ctrl+space?

Comment: What editor you are talking about? sublime or textmate?!

Comment: sublime text (I'm using windows)

Comment: It is very flexible editor. I'm using Textmate-like autocomplete plugin: https://github.com/alexstaubo/sublime_text_alternative_autocompletion And it can use textmate bundles. Even has plugin for Zen Coding.
If you can't find some syntax highlighter - just google with sublime word :) And you will find it!

Comment: http://www.adampatterson.ca/blog/2011/05/adding-sass-scss-support-sublime-edit-2/ - it's about SCSS and SASS
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/ - Tips and tricks.

Answer (score 4):

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) is a programmer's editor for the Windows platform and its syntax highlighting is easily configurable. It should be possible [to tweak](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=236) it to support the less syntax?

Comment: +1 Nice editor that is very easy to configure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm loving coding in [**Aptana IDE**](http://www.aptana.com/). It support up to date syntax like HTML5 tags (`video`, `nav`...) and CSS3  properties (`border-radius`, `transform` ...). It does not support Less naively but you can follow this([source](https://less.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/17-window-user-aptana-studio)) instruction to enable LESS too.

```
First step is to install LESS on Windows. If you already managed to install it head on over to Step 4!

Get Ruby for Windows from http://www.ruby-lang.org/ or -the easier- way: get the RubyInstaller for Windows from http://rubyinstaller.org/

Start Command Prompt with Ruby by clicking on Start --> Ruby 1.9xx --> Start Command Prompt with Ruby

Type in:
gem install less

If previous steps went fine you ready to use LESS. We just need to get Aptana to recognize our *.less fileformat. Let's go.

In Aptana, go to Window --> Preferences --> General --> Editors --> File Associations

Add a new file type named *.less

With the newly created *.less file type selected associate a editor below by clicking Add.. | Select "Aptana CSS Editor" (that one should be the one right at the top).

You're done!
```

Aptana is really up to date. So maybe they implemented the LESSCSS in the new build. Just check it out in their website.

Aptana Works with Mac and Windows and integrated with Git.

Comment: She asked about editor, not IDE. Aptana is really slow and it's community is not so active. It was my previous 'editor'.
If she need only html/css support without hard php or other lang support - it's not better solution.
P.S. But it's free :D

Answer (score 2):

Espresso, Coda, Sublime and TextMate text all have plugins for less syntax highlighting on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror has highlighting support for LESS (as well as JS, PHP, HTML). It's JavaScript (browser-based!), and has a way to add auto complete. Shouldn't be hard to add what you need if you've got the JS skills.

Answer (score 0):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io) is a great open-source code editor from Adobe, that has built-in LESS support with autocomplete and syntax highlighting.